# How can I Enable/Disable a tab in AppShell via binding ? It does not work for me, I am doing something wrong

Tags: tabs, maui

Please send me in the right direction here - I'm really confused.

See, I have this App.Shell:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="ExpensesMobile.AppShell"
    x:DataType="Login_VM:Login_VM"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:Approvals="clr-namespace:ExpensesMobile.View.Approvals"
    xmlns:Settings="clr-namespace:ExpensesMobile.View.AppSettings"
    xmlns:Login_VM="clr-namespace:ExpensesMobile.ViewModel.Login"
    xmlns:Login="clr-namespace:ExpensesMobile.View.Login"
    xmlns:Globals="clr-namespace:ExpensesMobile"
    xmlns:ExpenseReports="clr-namespace:ExpensesMobile.View.ExpenseReports"
    xmlns:res="clr-namespace:ExpensesMobile.Resources.Strings"
    Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.ExpenseReports}"
    Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled">
    
    <Shell.Items>
        <ShellContent x:Name="Login" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Login:Login}" Route="Login" Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" ></ShellContent>
    </Shell.Items>

    <TabBar Route="Login">
        <ShellContent ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Login:Login}" Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled" Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False" ></ShellContent>
    </TabBar>

    <TabBar x:Name="MyTabBar" Shell.NavBarHasShadow="true" Route="Home">
        <Tab
            x:Name="tabExpenseReports"
            Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.ExpenseReports}"
            Icon="ExpenseReports"
            Shell.BackgroundColor="#001933"
            Shell.ForegroundColor="#AB1300">

            <ShellContent
                x:Name="Pending"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate ExpenseReports:Pending}"
                Route="Pending"
                Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.Pending}"
                Icon="pending.svg"
                Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
            </ShellContent>

            <ShellContent
                x:Name="Finalized"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate ExpenseReports:Finalized}"
                Route="Finalized"
                Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.Finalized}"
                Icon="finalized.svg"
                Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>

        <Tab
            x:Name="tabApprovals"
            Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.Approvals}"
            Icon="approvals"
            IsEnabled="{Binding TabApprovalsIsEnabled}"
            Shell.BackgroundColor="#AB1300"
            Shell.ForegroundColor="#001933">

            <ShellContent
                x:Name="Approvals"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Approvals:Approvals}"
                Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
                Route="Approvals"
                Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.Approvals}"
                Icon="approvals.svg">
            </ShellContent>

            <ShellContent
                x:Name="Approved"
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate ExpenseReports:Approved}"
                Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
                Route="Approved"
                Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.Approved}"
                Icon="approved.svg">
            </ShellContent>
        </Tab>

        <Tab
            Title="{x:Static res:AppRes.Settings}"
            Icon="settings" Shell.BackgroundColor="#193300"
            x:Name="tabSettings">

            <ShellContent
                ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate Settings:Settings}"
                Route="Settings" />
        </Tab>
    </TabBar>
</Shell>
```

In the Login page I decide whether the logged-in user is an admin or not. If he isn't, then he shouldn't have access to the tab "Approvals".

I have tried in several ways to make the tab disabled in this case. This is what I have right now:

In the class "Globals" I have this (I have them in the Globals class because I will need to refer to these values across the application):

```
using ExpensesMobile.Model;

namespace ExpensesMobile
{
    public static class Globals
    {
        public static ExpensesMobileDB ExpensesMobileDB;

        public static LoginStatus loginStatus;

        public enum LoginStatus
        {
            loginRefused,
            loginAcceptedAdmin,
            loginAcceptedRegularUser
        }
    }
}
```

In Login_VM I have this code:

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using ExpensesMobile.Resources.Strings;
using ExpensesMobile.Services;
using ExpensesMobile.Utils;
using ExpensesMobile.View.ExpenseReports;
using System.Diagnostics;
using static ExpensesMobile.Globals;

namespace ExpensesMobile.ViewModel.Login
{
    [QueryProperty(nameof(Login), "Login")]
    public partial class Login_VM : Base_VM
    {
        public readonly LoginService loginService;

        private readonly IConnectivity connectivity;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string password;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool tabApprovalsIsEnabled = false;

        [ObservableProperty]
        private string username;

        public Login_VM(LoginService loginService, IConnectivity connectivity)
        {
            this.loginService = loginService;
            this.connectivity = connectivity;

            //TEMP CODE - DEBUG
            username = ".....";
            password = ".....";
        }

        private static async Task ShowToast(LoginStatus loginStatus)
        {
            string text;
            if (loginStatus == LoginStatus.loginAcceptedAdmin)
                text = AppRes.LoginConfirmationManager;
            else
                text = AppRes.LoginConfirmationUser;

            await Utils.Utils.ShowToast(text);
        }

        [RelayCommand]
        private async Task LoginAsync()
        {
            if (IsBusy)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                if (connectivity.NetworkAccess != NetworkAccess.Internet)
                {
                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(AppRes.MsgConnectivity1, AppRes.MsgConnectivity2, "OK"); //No connectivity, Please check your internet connection and then try again;
                    return;
                }

                IsBusy = true;

                LoginStatus loginStatus = LoginService.Login(username, password);
                if (loginStatus == LoginStatus.loginAcceptedAdmin)
                {
                    TabApprovalsIsEnabled = true;
                    await ShowToast(loginStatus);
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(Pending)}");
                }
                else if (LoginService.Login(username, password) == LoginStatus.loginAcceptedRegularUser)
                {
                    TabApprovalsIsEnabled = false;
                    await ShowToast(loginStatus);
                    await Shell.Current.GoToAsync($"//{nameof(Pending)}");
                }
                else if (LoginService.Login(username, password) == LoginStatus.loginRefused)
                {
                    await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(AppRes.Login, AppRes.LoginWrongUsernameOrPass, "OK"); //Wrong username and/or password !
                }

                Globals.loginStatus = loginStatus;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to login: {ex.Message}");
                ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                IsBusy = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I login as a regular user, the line 'tabApprovalsIsEnabled = false;' executes.

I have added this line because I wanted App.Shell to bind to Login_VM and not to Globals directly (that is a regular class, and has no knowledge of ObservableProperties).

However, although the tab Approvals has the xaml 'IsEnabled="{Binding TabApprovalsIsEnabled}"', this is not taken into consideration and my tab remains enabled.

Obviously I am missing something, and probably I am ignorant enough of the sequence of operations in MAUI - probably the code above executes and sets the property "tabApprovalsIsEnabled" to false AFTER the binding in AppShell has been done, I don't know....

How could I solve this problem, please ?

Thank you very much,
Alex.

Comment: You do not show where TabApprovalsIsEnabled is defined, but in your code you are setting the value of tabApprovalsIsEnabled (lowercase t) which is presumably a field and NOT the public property you are binding to

Comment: Hello, Jason. Thank you for your answer ! tabApprovalsIsEnabled is an observable property - I have edited my post ! Whether I change TabApprovalsIsEnabled or tabApprovalsIsEnabled makes no difference...

Comment: As a test, what happens if you have = false in definition? Instead of setting later. Does that work?

Comment: Steve, if I set it in Login_VM like so: [ObservableProperty] private bool tabApprovalsIsEnabled = false; then NO, it still does not work, although tabApprovalsIsEnabled is false. However, if I hardcode it in xaml like so: "IsEnabled="False" then YES, it works. So obviously it is the binding which is the problem....

Comment: Stop naming your property and field the same way. IF you have property "A" , the field is "_a", not "a". It is nightmare to debug and fix such random bugs, in code written in this manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should reset the value of  property `TabApprovalsIsEnabled`  not `tabApprovalsIsEnabled` .

Please refer to the following code:

```
[RelayCommand]
private async Task LoginAsync()
{
     // other code

    try
    {
         // other code

        LoginStatus loginStatus = LoginService.Login(username, password);
        if (loginStatus == LoginStatus.loginAcceptedAdmin)
        {
            // replace `tabApprovalsIsEnabled` with `TabApprovalsIsEnabled`
            //tabApprovalsIsEnabled = true;
             
             TabApprovalsIsEnabled = true;

            //........
        }
        else if (LoginService.Login(username, password) == LoginStatus.loginAcceptedRegularUser)
        {
          // replace `tabApprovalsIsEnabled` with `TabApprovalsIsEnabled`
           // tabApprovalsIsEnabled = false;

              TabApprovalsIsEnabled = true;
             

        }
        else if (LoginService.Login(username, password) == LoginStatus.loginRefused)
        {
            //Wrong username and/or password !
            await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert(AppRes.Login, AppRes.LoginWrongUsernameOrPass, "OK"); 
        }

        Globals.loginStatus = loginStatus;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Unable to login: {ex.Message}");
        ErrorHandling.HandleError(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        IsBusy = false;
    }
}
```

**Note:**

We need set `BindingContext` for `AppShell.xaml.cs`. Then if we change the value of property `TabApprovalsIsEnabled`  of the current ViewModel, the UI could refresh automatically.

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell 
{

    Login_VM _VM;
    public AppShell()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Routing.RegisterRoute("DetailPage", typeof(DetailPage));

        _VM = new Login_VM();

        this.BindingContext = _VM;  
    }

    [Obsolete]
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();


        Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), () =>
        {

            _VM.TabApprovalsIsEnabled = false;

            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jessie, but I had already changed that. To no avail. But I was thinking that maybe (just maybe) the xaml in AppShell.xaml is computed BEFORE I set TabApprovalsIsEnabled = false and is never revisited again. I am not at all sure about that, though - it's just an idea about what the cause might be. I don't know whether the xaml in AppShell is ever read again during the life of the app.

Comment: Could you please post the code of  `AppShell.xaml` ,`AppShell.xaml.cs` and the `Login_VM ` ?

Comment: I did a test based on your code, and I could reproduce this problem. But after I changed the property to `TabApprovalsIsEnabled `, then it works on my side.

Comment: You can recheck if you have set the BindContext for `AppShell.xaml.cs` correctly. And recheck if event `LoginAsync()` could be executed.

Comment: Jessie, I have modified the original post to include the *full* AppShell and the full Login_VM code. Yes, if I set a breakpoint in Login_VM on 'TabApprovalsIsEnabled = false;' it will be hit. The binding seems to be to be set properly i.e. x:DataType="Login_VM:Login_VM" and IsEnabled="{Binding TabApprovalsIsEnabled}" The code compiles okay. But.... Could it be because the page I am navigating to (see LoginAsync()), which is called Pending, has some VERY ODD "XAML binding failures" ? I cannot find the reason of those binding problems - the code works just fine on that page.

Comment: When is the event `LoginAsync`  invoked? We should change the value of property `TabApprovalsIsEnabled `  on current `BindContext` of  `AppShell.xaml.cs` .

Comment: You can check the updated part of my answer.

Comment: Jessie, AppShell is listed above. AppShell.xaml.cs contains as the last line CurrentItem = Login; Then, in the login VM (which is listed above), there is the RelayCommand "LoginAsync" which gets executed when you click on the Login button. This code sets the ObservableProperty TabApprovalsIsEnabled to false. AppShell.xaml contains (see code above) the line x:DataType="Login_VM:Login_VM". Therefore, the tab binding IsEnabled="{Binding TabApprovalsIsEnabled}" should be correct. It is NOT signaled by a squiggly red line. So I think that everything is correct. And yet it doesn't work :-(

Comment: `AppShell.xaml.cs contains as the last line CurrentItem = Login;`  But I couldn't find that you set the BindContext for your `AppShell`.

Comment: Is the `Login_VM ` view model the `BindContext` for your `LoginPage`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have the code: public partial class Login : ContentPage
{
    public Login(Login_VM viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}

Comment: Hi @Alex, you set the `Login_VM ` for the `BindingContext` of   `Login ` Page, but you didn't set `BindingContext` for `AppShell` . Even if you change the value of  property `TabApprovalsIsEnabled  ` in class  `Login_VM`, it will not affect the UI of  `Appshell` .

Comment: Now I am utterly confused. On what object should I set the BindingContext of AppShell ? In AppShell.xaml I have the line x:DataType="Login_VM:Login_VM". Is this not setting the data context ?

Comment: Yes, it is not setting the data context.

Comment: I cannot see other codes. Could you please post a basic demo so that I can help you better?

Comment: Hurray !!! Thank you, Jessie ! You have sent me onto the right path ! It works now ! I have added the line AppShell.Current.BindingContext = viewModel; into the constructor of the login page ! Great !!! ;-) Thank you !

Comment: Now Login.Xaml.Cs looks like this: 

public partial class Login : ContentPage
{
    public Login(Login_VM viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        AppShell.Current.BindingContext = viewModel;
    }
}